# Pass multiple parameters (complex objects) into action method from ajax call in .NET Core 3 MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-3.1

The following is an example of the basic structure/goal:

**javascript ajax structure:**

```
helper = someBaseClass.extend({
    init: function () {
    },
    makeRequest: function (options) {
        return createAjaxObservable(
            {
                url: options.url,
                data: JSON.stringify(options.data), //stringify is present
                type: options.type,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false
            });
    }
});
```

**server javascript request:**

```
this.helper.makeRequest({ url: "/Session/RequestSomeInfo", type: "POST", data: { sessionId: options.sessionId, requestSomeInfo: { isActive: true } });
```

Request some arbitary info on sessionId, for all arbitary entities that are active.
I am using post here for testing purposes.

**controller method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RequestSomeInfo(Session sessionId, RequestSomeInfo request)
{
    //implement api connection 
    //request some arbitary info on sessionid, for all arbitary entities that are active.
    
    return CreateJson(true, new { Data = requestSomeInfoResponse.Data });
}
```

The above is the ideal solution.
I am aware it may not be possible.
What would be the best alternative solution?

I have omitted [FromBody]. [FromBody] I understand only will pass one parameter. I can get the above general structure to work, using[FromBody], but it'll only pass one parameter.
I have also tried using a wrapper class - which contains Session and RequestSomeInfo, then passing this wrapper class. This also works.
However, the problem being that RequestSomeInfo could be requesting different things across an extensive web app. For example, RequestSomeInfo could be RequestCustomerNames, RequestActivities, RequestSocialConnections, etc.
--> the objects I want to pass can get complex.

I can use abstraction, or generics to accomplish this. Using generics on the wrapper class works, and is so far the best solution, however, this isn't the ideal solution. Ideally, I want to implement the above basic goal and structure as closely as possible.

Comment: can you click 'accept this answer', please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax cannot map multiple complex types at the same time, it can only pass *multiple basic types* at the same time. A better approach is to create a **ViewModel** to refer to these two complex types.

Since you did not give the full ajax implementation code, I use jQuery's ajax as an example. The `Session` here is customized by default.

Here is the all model.

```
public class Session
{
    public int sessionId { get; set; }
}
public class RequestSomeInfo
{
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public Session  Session { get; set; }
    public RequestSomeInfo RequestSomeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The Ajax code is as follows (it put in Index.cshtml).

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Session/RequestSomeInfo',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                session: {
                    sessionId: '123'
                },
                requestSomeInfo: { isActive: true }
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        })
    })
```

The controller is changed like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RequestSomeInfo(ViewModel viewModel)
    { 
        return Json(viewModel);
    }
```

And you can get this result.

[image]